# The loop iterates for only one time

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a list from an API and them iterate on it in the for loop to create an instance of some class from every single item in it. But the for loop works for only the first iteration and doesn't move on. The statement `print('loop DONE!')`; isn't reached and I can't know what's wrong. May someone helps me, please?

[image]

I used print statements to find out where the problem is and all what I got is that ONLY the first iteration works.

Comment: Please don’t include code as an image (for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)) and instead edit your question to include code as text

Comment: Do a `print(results)` to check the incoming data before entering the loop.

Comment: This question was already asked and answered on slack.  Please delete it from here, or copy your answer over for historical purposes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.